# The verb "dope" here

Tags: word-meaning

I am currently read [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/north-koreas-economy-shrinks-most-033931177.html) and could someone help me in what sense the verb "dope" is used here?

> "This suggests that there's been a massive increase in domestic use of coal and minerals. This is such a crucial export commodity and now that very little of it is being sold abroad, as compared to normal years, domestic industry is probably getting financially **doped** by cheap energy at the moment given how much of production is still going on," he said.

So would it mean North Korea is administered drugs (cheap energy) like a drug addict?

FYI the definition of the Merriam Unabridged. (Googling didn't help).

> 1
>   a :  to smear or lubricate with dope
>
> b :  to apply dope to (as the fabric of an airplane or balloon)
>
> 2
>   a :  to introduce an adulterant into (a food) or an additive into (a fluid)
>
> b :  to treat or impregnate with a foreign substance to impart a desired appearance or property :  doctor
>
> 3
>   a :  to give a stupefying or exhilarating drug to :  drug
>
> b :  to put a stupefying drug into
>
> c :  to administer a drug to (a horse) to increase or decrease speed in a race
>
> d :  to induce inaction, apathy, or submissiveness in by a mental diet designed to produce such qualities or attitudes
>
> 4
>   slang :  to work out from one's interpretation of available information a forecast about the outcome of (a competition) or the performance or placing of (competitors)

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the choice of words in the article are rather bad but here is my answer. You should link two words in the part sentence "domestic industry is probably getting **financially doped** by cheap energy at the moment". 
Then taking the definition of the Merriam Unabridged 3b : to put a stupefying drug into. 
We can assume the writer is trying to say that **the domestic industry is financially insensitive and slow to react because of the cheap energy available.**
stupefy (ˈstjuːpɪˌfaɪ)
vb (tr) , -fies, -fying or -fied
1. to render insensitive or lethargic

Comment: I personally think that the massive increase in domestic use of coal and minerals, now that very little of it is being sold abroad, is politically motivated rather than financially. With the producers and user having very little to say in what they are allowed to do.